# help with preg_match_all and creating default values

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I'm in need for php help/expertise to tweak/change this preg_match_all function. What I want to do is create default values for missing ordered pairs. It is matching the data correctly, but I need some logic to add some default values. (see EXPECTING data output below). Can this be handled within this same function? Thanks!

preg_match_all snippet:

```
foreach ($InputFile as $line){
    preg_match_all("/([0-9])-([^=]+)=([^;]+);/", $line, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
    $LineData = array();
    foreach ($matches as $information)
        $LineData[$information[2]] = $information[3];
    $data[] = $LineData;
print_r($LineData);
}
```

The data file has a max of (8) attributes in this order:

```
1-Server
2-Logdate
3-BackupSet
4-StartTime
5-Duration
6-DBServer
7-Size
8-Status
```

But there are instances in the file, where there are lines that do NOT have all the attributes, such as 5-Duration, 7-Size, 8-Status. I want to place a default value for these attributes something like:

```
5-Duration => 0
7-Size     => 0
8-Status   => incomplete
```

Array output: (current)

```
Array ( [Server] => hostname3.prop.abc
        [Logdate] => Wed Jan 05 2011
        [BackupSet] => rfoo101.az1
        [StartTime] => 20110105000004
        [Duration] => 00:56:47
        [DBServer] => rfoo101.prop.az1.kaz.com 
        [Size] => 56.51
        [Status] => Backup succeeded )
Array ( [Server] => hostname3.prop.abc
        [Logdate] => Wed Jan 05 2011
        [BackupSet] => bar202.az4_lvm
        [StartTime] => 20110105040003
        [DBServer] => bar202.prop.az4.kaz.com) 
Array ( [Server] => hostname10.prop.az2
        [Logdate] => Thu Jan 06 2011
        [BackupSet] => bar201_az2_lvm
        [StartTime] => 20110106151622
        [DBServer] => bar201.prop.az2.kaz.com  
        [Status] => Backup failed )
```

Expecting data output: (WITH DEFAULT VALUES)

```
Array ( [Server] => hostname3.prop.abc
        [Logdate] => Wed Jan 05 2011
        [BackupSet] => rfoo101.az1
        [StartTime] => 20110105000004
        [Duration] => 00:56:47
        [DBServer] => rfoo101.prop.az1.kaz.com 
        [Size] => 56.51
        [Status] => Backup succeeded )
Array ( [Server] => hostname3.prop.abc
        [Logdate] => Wed Jan 05 2011
        [BackupSet] => bar202.az4_lvm
        [StartTime] => 20110105040003
        [Duration] => 0 
        [DBServer] => bar202.prop.az4.kaz.com 
        [Size]     => 0  
        [Status]   => incomplete) 
Array ( [Server] => hostname10.prop.az2
        [Logdate] => Thu Jan 06 2011
        [BackupSet] => bar201_az2_lvm
        [StartTime] => 20110106151622
        [Duration]  => 0
        [DBServer] => bar201.prop.az2.kaz.com 
        [Size]   => 0 
        [Status] => Backup failed )
```

Code changes per help:

```
<?php
$defaults = array(
    'Duration' => 0,
    'Size'     => 0,
    'Status'   => 'incomplete' );

$data = array();
$InputFile = file("test.txt");

foreach ($InputFile as $line){
    preg_match_all("/([0-9])-([^=]+)=([^;]+);/", $line, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER); 
    $LineData = array();
    foreach ($matches as $information)                  
        $LineData[$information[2]] = $information[3];  
    $data[] = array_merge($defaults, $LineData);
}

print_r($data);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make an array of default values and then use [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) to create an output array that has the default values except where overridden by values from the parsed match:

```
$defaults = array(
    'Duration' => 0,
    'Size' => 0,
    'Status' => 'incomplete' );

$output_with_defaults = array_merge($defaults, $output_without_defaults);
```

This works due to the following behavior from `array_merge()`:

> If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the later value for that key will overwrite the previous one.

For your case, you'd want to modify this line:

```
$data[] = $LineData;
```

to be...

```
$data[] = array_merge($defaults, $LineData);
```

(And declare the defaults array before the start of any of the current code - it doesn't need to be inside any loops.)

Comment: pretty interesting. would i plug this after the preg_match_all function within the foreach? thanks.

Comment: I edited in a more details explanation for your particular case.

Comment: Hi amber, i posted my code on top with your input. I can't get the merge to work yet. something is out of order. thx

Comment: I edited the code you posted. Note that it was actually working (aside from the unnecessary replication of my example call to array_merge), but your print statement was printing the unmodified version of the array. I've changed it to use a `print_r()` call of `$data` afterwards, which will show the modified version.

Answer (score 0):

You probably can assign a default array structure, like

```
if (!is_array($LineData))
{
  $LineData = 
  array(
    'Server'    => ...,
    'Logdate'   => ...,
    'BackupSet' => ...,
    'StartTime' => ...,
    'Duration'  => 0,
    'DBServer'  => ...,
    'Size'      => 0,
    'Status'    => 'incomplete',
  );
}
foreach ($matches as $information)
{
  $LineData[$information[2]] = $information[3];
}
$data[] = $LineData;
```

Comment: would this be after the preg_match_all function?

Comment: @cjd143SD - Before you initiate $LineData. This is just to ensure all matches is start with an array with some default value. So, if some of the information is not available, it will use the default value, not much diff from @Amber question